# Mark as Resolved all alerts in gitlab project

Tags: gitlab, alerts

How can i mark all gitlab alters as *Resolved* for my project?

There's no button to select and mark all alerts in monitor -> alerts

Comment: What do you mean by alerts? May Notifications?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/operations/incident_management/alerts.html